# How can I expand a Gtk Label to fill the entire Horizontal Space?

Tags: gtk, label, pygtk

I'm trying to insert a text label in a dialog but when I set the aligment to (X=0, Y=0.5) and the line wrap to True, the text doesn't fill the entire horizontal space.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKn3Q.png) is an image

It is the example code in python:

```
import gtk

if __name__ == "__main__":

    lbl = gtk.Label('Presione el botón "Adelante" para iniciar la instalación del sistema. Después de este paso no podrá detener la instalación, así que asegúrese de que sus datos son correctos.')
    lbl.set_line_wrap(True)
    lbl.set_alignment(0, 0.5)
    lbl.set_justify(gtk.JUSTIFY_FILL)
    lbl.show()

    diag = gtk.Dialog()
    diag.set_size_request(640, 480)
    diag.vbox.pack_start(lbl)
    diag.run()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try setting "expand" and "fill" properties when you pack the label into the dialog:

```
diag.vbox.pack_start(lbl, True, True, 0)
```

**Edit**

You are correct. Sorry. Per the GTK Reference Manual:

> Note that setting line wrapping to TRUE does not make the label wrap at its parent container's width, because GTK+ widgets conceptually can't make their requisition depend on the parent container's size. For a label that wraps at a specific position, set the label's width using gtk_widget_set_size_request().

Therefore, set the size request on the `GtkLabel` instead of the `GtkDialog` and then the dialog and let the dialog size itself from that.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import gtk

if __name__ == "__main__":

    lbl = gtk.Label('Presione el botón "Adelante" para iniciar la instalación del sistema. Después de este paso no podrá detener la instalación, así que asegúrese de que sus datos son correctos.')
    lbl.set_line_wrap(True)
    lbl.set_alignment(0, 0.5)
    lbl.set_justify(gtk.JUSTIFY_FILL)
    lbl.set_size_request(640, 480)
    lbl.show()

    diag = gtk.Dialog()
    diag.set_resizable(True)
    diag.vbox.pack_start(lbl, True, True, 0)
    diag.run()
```

Comment: I've try to do that and the result is the same. Changing the parameters makes some changes but never expand the text to the right side.

Comment: Thanks, that work fine to me doing this:

`lbl.set_size_request(WIDTH, -1)`

Comment: What if I don't have `pack_start`, what if my container only has `add`?